# How does Nodejs/V8 know how big a native object is?

Tags: node.js, opencv, matrix, garbage-collection

Specifically, in node-opencv, opencv Matrix objects are represented as a javascript object wrapping a c++ opencv Matrix.

However, if you don't .release() them manually, the V8 engine does not seem to know how big they are, and the NodeJS memory footprint can grow far beyond any limits you try to set on the command line; i.e. it only seems to run the GC when it approaches the set memory limits, but because it does not see the objects as large, this does not happen until it's too late.

Is there something we can add to the objects which will allow V8 to see them as large objects?

Illustrating this, you can create and 'forget' large 1M buffers all day on a nodejs set to limit it's memory to 256Mbytes.

But if you do the same with 1M opencv Matrices, NodeJS will quickly use much more than the 256M limit - unless you either run GC manually, or release the Matrices manually.

(caveat: a c++ opencv matrix is a reference to memory; i.e. more than one Matrix object can point to the same data - but it would be a start to have V8 see ALL references to the same memory as being the size of that memory for the purposes of GC, safer that seeing them as all very small.)

Circumstances: on an RPi3, we have a limited memory footprint, and processing live video (using about 4M of mat objects per frame) can soon exhaust all memory.
Also, the environment I'm working in (a Node-Red node) is designed for 'public' use, so difficult to ensure that all users completely understand the need to manually .release() images; hence this question is about how to bring this large data under the GC's control.

Comment: Can you maybe reuse your old mats after you finish processing?

Comment: the problem is that we're trying to make something that works for joe public; so it's got to be resilient against them not hearing the need to release or reuse :(  - but it's an idea I had not considered, thankyou...

Comment: Are you sure the matrices aren't released? Usually once you leave the scope where you create a matrix and reference it only in a local variable it will automatically release, atleast that's my experience. You shouldn't have to call gc manually, maybe that's a different story on RPI. Did you try implementing std::out in the Mat destructor in order to see, whether they are actually released.

Comment: yes, they are released, but only when Node thinks it's about to hit it's memory limit.  The trouble is that node believes that each mat is only a few hundred bytes, not their actual size of 1Mbyte.  For example, you can allocate new Buffer objects of 1M each all day as long as you don't keep a reference to them, but with 1M matrices, this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can inform v8 about your external memory usage with [`AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemory(int64_t delta)`](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-12.0/d5/dda/classv8_1_1_isolate.html#ae1a59cac60409d3922582c4af675473e). There are wrappers for this function in [n-api](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/n-api.html#n_api_napi_adjust_external_memory) and [NAN](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/v8_internals.md#api_nan_adjust_external_memory).

---

By the way, "large objects" has a special meaning in v8: objects large enough to be created in large object space and never moved. External memory is off-heap memory and I think what you're referring to.